# form still returns false even when one of radios is being checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, radio-button

Why is it that when one of gender radios is being checked the form still returns false?

HTML

```
<form action="">
    <input class="radio_male" type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"> Male
    <br>
    <input class="radio_female" type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"> Female
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('form').onsubmit = function() {
    if(!$('.radio_male').checked || !$('.radio_female').checked) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you state what will be the output?.

Comment: Link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/Lz44tk7d/)

Comment: @JTrixx16 [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/q97o8bh7/3/) is the sample that I made. If you want to determine if the checkbox is true or false

Answer (score 2):

You want to check that is any one of option is selected so do following,

```
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('form').onsubmit = function() {
    if($('.radio_male').checked || $('.radio_female').checked) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Link to [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/Lz44tk7d/1/)

**Explanation**
According to your following condition,
`if(!$('.radio_male').checked || !$('.radio_female').checked) {`
You are checking that if `Female` is not selected or `male` is not selected then `false` which is logically wrong as always there will be either `female` not selected(when `male` is selected) or `male` not selected(when `female` is selected) or both not-selected(default state), so that condition will always yield `true`.
So in my suggested answer, we are checking first that either `male` is selected or `female` is selected then `true,` else `false`.

Comment: I didn't think about that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read your code out aloud to yourself. You are asking `if male isn't checked OR female isn't checked`

Since the radio buttons only ever let one option be selected, this condition will always run.

Your simplest solution is to change from OR to AND

`if(!$('.radio_male').checked && !$('.radio_female').checked)`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lz44tk7d/2/

Comment: This is also helpful. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To check if radio or checkbox is checked using jQuery, it's:

```
$('.radio_male').is(':checked')
```

Comment: Thanks. But I prefer vanilla JS

Answer (score 0):

You could just reverse your codes where you checked if one of them is checked then return true and else return false or you could try to use && rather than or to checked if the radio button are checked.